# String Encryption Algorithm

Tags: python, list

I have a string encryption algorithm which converts a inputted string into list of string . The output is supposed to be the first letter of every list element(string here).
example in the list1 below

output is supposed to be 'tir hsy ia st'
and 
list2 output should be 'tir hsy iat sto'

But with the code i'm having it is able to print the output only if every list element(string here) contains same number of letters otherwise(in case of list 1) it raises "string index out of range".

The ceil here indicates the number of letters in each list element.(4 here in this case)

How do i go about printing the output of list1 in the way shown?
p.s-i'm beginner in python

```
list1=['this','isat','ry']

list2=['this','isat','ryto']
```

my code to print the output

```
for elem in range(ceil):
        for i in range(len(list1)):
            if list1[elem][i]:
                print(list1[i][elem],end='')
        print(end=' ')
```

Comment: It's not clear how to arrive at the expected output. Should not one of the expected characters be *a*?

Comment: yeah right..nice observation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you expect `if list[elem][i]` to be false if `i` is not a member of `list[elem]` but that's not what it does. Rather, Python tries to check if the value is truthy or not, and when there *isn't* a value there at all, you get in `IndexError`.

Anyway, rather than look before you leap, you could just ask for forgiveness instead of permission:

```
list1=['this','isat','ry']

for elem in range(len(list1[0])):
        for i in range(len(list1)):
            try:
                print(list1[i][elem],end='')
            except IndexError:
                continue
        print(end=' ')
```

If you prefer the "look before you leap" variant, the proper way to check if the index is there is

```
            if i in list1[elem]:
```

I assumed the first element of the list will always have the maximum length, so we simply loop over that in the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

All you were missing really is a check to see if your element is long enough to avoid the value error. I also added inline code to generate what i assume your ceil was.

```
for i in range(max([len(i) for i in list1])):
   for j in list1:
     if i < len(j):
       print(j[i], end='')
   print(end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` instead:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
print(' '.join(map(''.join, zip_longest(*list1, fillvalue=''))))
```

This outputs:

```
tir hsy ia st
```